# -v flag for named volumes Docker?

Tags: docker, docker-volume

I want to create a Docker volume but since the commands for volumes and bind mounts are the same every time I use the `-v` flag I get a bind mount.

```
 docker run -d \
  --name devtest \
  -v myvol2:/app \
  nginx:latest

 docker run -d \
  -it \
  --name devtest \
  -v "$(pwd)"/target:/app \
  nginx:latest
```

Comment: If you want to create a volume, use `docker volume create`

Comment: Why do you think the first form gives you a bind mount?

Comment: @DavidMaze because I tried running it this way and in inspect it said it was a bind mount

Comment: basically, I don't understand how does docker know if we want to set up a volume or bind mount if we are using the same flag `-v`?

Comment: In the first half of the `-v` option, the named volume `myvol` doesn't contain a slash, but the absolute host path `/home/myname/target` does.